# Why do I need the second argument?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a method

```
class FooInterface {
    bool put(uint8_t* array, unsigned array_length);
}
```

The test needs to verify that array of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, which has 5 elements is being passed to the `put` In My `TEST_F()`, I have the following code.

```
uint8_t arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // Values for 'array' the out parameter

MockFoo foo;
FooInterface* fooI = &foo;

EXPECT_CALL(foo, put(_, 5))
    .With(Args<0,1>(ElementsAreArray(arr, 5)));
```

This seems to work, but it is driving me crazy because, it seems like instead of `Args<0,1>`, I should have `Args<0>` since I am matching array for the first parameter and the array size is set to `5`.  Changing to:

```
EXPECT_CALL(BFO, put(_, 5))
    .With(Args<0>(ElementsAreArray(arr, 5)));  // Here is 'Args<0>'
```

Produces these errors:

```
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3114:34: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *>'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  typedef typename StlContainer::value_type Element;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3532:28: note: in instantiation of template class 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &>' requested here                                                                                                                                        
    return MakeMatcher(new ElementsAreMatcherImpl<Container>(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:555:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char>::operator Matcher<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &>' requested here                                                                                     
    return polymorphic_matcher_or_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:531:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &, testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char> >::CastImpl' requested here                                                                         
    return CastImpl(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:628:45: note: in instantiation of member function 'testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &, testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char> >::Cast' requested here                                                                             
    return internal::MatcherCastImpl<T, M>::Cast(polymorphic_matcher_or_value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:666:34: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::SafeMatcherCastImpl<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &>::Cast<testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char> >' requested here                                                                  
  return SafeMatcherCastImpl<T>::Cast(polymorphic_matcher);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                 ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h:221:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::SafeMatcherCast<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *> &, testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char> >' requested here                                                                  
      : inner_matcher_(SafeMatcherCast<const SelectedArgs&>(inner_matcher)) {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                       ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h:288:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::internal::ArgsMatcherImpl<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *, unsigned int> &, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1>::ArgsMatcherImpl<testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char> >' 
    return MakeMatcher(new ArgsMatcherImpl<ArgsTuple, k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/sporty/ws-ccs/hw_1_5/miwt-os/coap/unittest/cbor_encoder_test.cpp:176:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'testing::internal::ArgsMatcher<testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<unsigned char>, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1>::operator Matcher<const std::tr1::tuple<const unsigned char *, unsigned int> &>' requested here  
        .With(Args<0>(ElementsAreArray(arr, 5)));
              ^
```

Comment: The first parameter is a pointer, `uint8_t*`, not an array.

Comment: @molbdnilo What do you mean?   First argument is a pointer to array, can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: It's a pointer to *one* `uint8_t`, not to an array. The `uint8_t` it points to happens to be the first element of an array, but the compiler is totally unaware of that.

Comment: @molbdnilo, so why `Args<0,1>` within `With()` works and `Args<0>` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is not an array; it is simply an address to a spot in memory.  The system has zero way of knowing how long the memory you reserved for the array is.  The second argument is specifically for that purpose.  You know when you create it how long it is so you have to pass that information along.

However, unless you are forbidden to do so, I would recommend taking the time to learn how to use templates to handle your arrays and array type structures.  The std::array is very nice and has all kinds of bells and whistles you can use.  Best of all it handles all of the hassle that goes with maintaining your array.

Comment: Looking at gmock CheatSheet, the parameters inside <> identify the argument number, the array length is specifed by the 5 in the following: `ElementsAreArray(arr, 5)`.  I may be missing something, but I believe this is the case.  I am working on the tests for low level code where std::array was not used, it is not up to me.